# Function or code to compare multiple sheets in Excel and display them sorted in ascending order in a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has let's say 3 similar worksheets. Each from different supplier. I want to compare them to find out who is cheaper and who is the cheapest with each and every item. 
For example:

Worksheet 1 (D) (stands for David)

```
    A            B             C             D
    1            quality 1     quality 2     quality 3    .....
    2 Apple      20            30            40
    3 Orange     25            33            46
```

Worksheet 2 (O) (stands for Oliver)

```
    A            B             C             D
    1            quality 1     quality 2     quality 3    .....
    2 Apple      18            30            35
    3 Orange     25            35            46
```

Worksheet 3 (H) (stands for Harry)

```
    A            B             C             D
    1            quality 1     quality 2     quality 3    .....
    2 Apple      22            33            44
    3 Orange     20            36            39
```

I expect the output to be something like this:

Worksheet 4 (sorted by the cheapest)

```
    A            B             C             D
    1            quality 1     quality 2     quality 3    .....
    2 Apple      O;D;H         D=O;H         O;D;H
    3 Orange     H;D=O         D;O;H         H;D=O
```

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: as a new user, please take the [tour], then learn [ask]. Edit your question before it gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's tough about this one is that Excel ranges can't really cross worksheets, it isn't really 3D.  So in VBA you'll probably end up with:

- An Array of sheet names for your 3 (or more?) sheets to be compared
- A loop to pull the values from a given 2D address across the array of sheets into an Array
- Sort the Array (which isn't a thing, you have to dump the array into a temp range somewhere and sort that, along with a list of sheet names)
- A loop to go down the sorted array's temp range, naming the sheets in order and putting in either an equals sign or semicolon depending on the next value
- which all constructs a string of the type in your output sheet.

...I'd do all that as an Excel function, then copy the function into all the cells of Sheet4, since the names of sheets1-3 are hard-coded into the function.

If you want to be able to do this for any arbitrary list of sheets, trickier still.

But before we get into that, do you have a lot of this 3D data processing to do?  Because Excel has a powerful tool for multi-dimensional data, called a Pivot Table, and your data is eminently suitable for putting into a pivot table, and this would allow you to "pivot" the data so that "which supplier" becomes a column or row, rather than sheet.

Pivot tables have a learning curve, but they're the way to go for this kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roy Brander!
Yes, I have 9 sheets, each of them has 60 rows and AZ columns.
If putting all data in one sheet will make it easier I can do that.
Pivot Table tool can summarize my data put could it compare them the way I want? Because summarizing them is not important for me, instead comparing each cell is what matters.
Any more information could be helpful Mr. Roy. Thank you again!

Comment: There's nothing that can produce the long string of letters and punctuation marks you specified, but a pivot table could show the 9 values that are all in (say) cell C7, as a column of 9 values - and then sort those, so that you can see which are equal and which are greater than the next;  I wondered if that might eliminate the need for your string of sorted sheet names and "=;" marks.    It would also be much easier to write a macro to produce that string if you already had the sorted list.    HOWEVER, my question was whether you have a lot of different things to do or just this one job.

Comment: If you just have this one thing to do, then the work to move the data into a pivot table is not worth it; less time to just write the longer macro that does what I outlined in my answer.  

This isn't a code-writing service, but if the steps outlined in my answer don't seem to be within your ability, I could provide some code fragments for the harder steps.

Oh, and I see you're new here.   It's polite to "thank" answers that you feel are useful by  clicking on that little up-arrow beside the useful answer, to indicate it WAS rated as an answer, and not a bad thing.

Comment: I actually did voted your answer but I get this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
As appreciation of your efforts I will accept your answer so you earns +15 reputation I guess.

Comment: I'm a VBA beginner. What I've tried is oppening a new sheet and in the first cell of it I wrote: =D!B2,O!B2,H!B2
And then I dragged the handle to copy the formula to all cells in the new sheet.
Now each cell has all the prices. However, I still need to do the comparison work manually.